# AngularJS app fails to start when in subdirectory

Tags: angularjs, apache, mod-rewrite

Our DocumentRoot is in /var/www but I was told to create different directories for different applications. I suggested virtual named based hosting config but they turned it down.

The directories are

```
/var/www/app1
/var/www/app2
/var/www/app3
```

Rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

So I put the first app in /var/www/app1 but I'm getting an issue.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and the minified js files in Chrome Dev Tools are showing as html files

What should I fix in my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now. RewriteBase is the key